# jQuery/HTML5 FileAPI: Why does no drag event appear to be triggering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, fileapi

Why is nothing happening here when I drag a file over the imageContainer div?  Nothing in the console, nothing on the page, etc.

```
<div id="imageContainer" style="height: 724px; width: 100%; "></div>

...

$('#imageContainer').on({
    dragenter: function dragEnter() {
        console.log('enter');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'lightBlue');
    },
    dragleave: function dragLeave() {
        console.log('leave');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    },
    dragover: false,
    drop: function dragDrop (e) {
        console.log('drop');
        jQuery.each(e.dataTransfer.files, function (index, file) {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = (function (file) {
                return function (e) {
                    $(this).append('<div class="dataurl"><strong>' + file.fileName + '</strong>' + e.target.result + '</div>');
                };
            })(file);
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run it on Firefox with Firebug is says:

```
e.dataTransfer is undefined
```

So you would like to change it with:

```
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer
```

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/78fdH/)

Comment: Oops!  Even fixed, though, that's not the cause.  Still the same problem.

Comment: ^^ Related to an earlier answer.  :D

Comment: Hmmm, I'd been using Chrome only to this point.  Something in my script seems to have both Chrome and Firefox swallowing any errors, which is unfortunate, so I can't see this same.  In Firefox, at least the blue/white color change happens, but nothing at all happens in Chrome.  Re the drop event, which this answer specifically applies to, I'll have to guess that this answer is right; perhaps the code itself is wrong there at the moment, since dropping an image still does nothing in Chrome, and in Firefox, it just loads the image as a new page, just like normal.

Comment: So I guess this question might be better phrased, "jQuery/HTML5 FileAPI: Why does no drag event appear to be triggering *in Chrome*?"  w/r/t there being no color change.

Comment: The fiddle seems to work in Chrome w/ color changes, so I'm going to guess its something greasemonkey+chrome+fileAPI specific which still is unID'd.  So I'll set this as the answer to the actual question I asked, but still keep looking for the fix I need.  :D

Comment: I hope you'll find and fix the issue in drop event.

Comment: Well, here's the full script, if anyone has any ideas :D
https://github.com/brianfreud/greasemonkey-batchCAA/blob/fefab2a285fecc1a4759e137eaf2acb2510deea8/testing.user.js

Comment: Turns out it was the Chrome security model for file:// urls causing the problem.  Since I was working on the userscript locally, Chrome was applying the same domain file:// rules.  Using the -allow-file-access-from-files switch made Chrome begin behaving again, and things began to work just like Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things.

First of all make sure you load the page using the http: instead of file: scheme. With file: your drop event will fire but FileReader will fail silently.

Next in the FileReader.onload you are adding the html to **this** which is the FileReader. Try adding it to an html element instead. In the code below #files point to a list.

Finally the dataURL is embeded in the html, use the Elements inspector to check, but not visible in the markup.

```
$(function () {
    $('#dropTarget').on({
        dragenter: function dragEnter() {
            console.log('enter');
            $(this).css('background-color', 'lightBlue');
        },
        dragleave: function dragLeave() {
            console.log('leave');
            $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
        },
        dragover: false,
        drop: function dragDrop(e) {
            console.log('drop');
            jQuery.each(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files, function (index, file) {
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = function () {
                    console.log(this.result);
                    $('#files').append('<div class="dataurl"><strong>' + file.fileName + '</strong>' + this.result + '</div>');
                };

                fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            });
        }
    });
});
```